# Is it possible to open and close a custom floating filter in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Is it possible to open and close or to show and hide custom floating filters in ag-grid, for example if a button was clicked?
If you initialize the table, only the header should be visible. Then after a specific button was clicked, also the floating filters below the header should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gridOptions.floatingFilter = !gridOptions.floatingFilter;
gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
```