# How to update defaultColDef in agGrid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having a custom column filter with a button toggle.By default, the column filter is set to false. When I click on the button the column filter is toggled by setting the floatingFilter: true. While the floatingFilter becomes true during the button click it doesn't show the filter.

Whereas if we make the floatingFilter to be true by default at that time it shows the filter after that if we toggle the button to show/hide the floatingFilter it works expected.

May i know how to update the defaultColDef dynamically in ag-grid to make the floatingFilter to be true during button click.

defaultColDef:

```
this.defaultColumnDefs = {
      suppressMenu: true,
      suppressMovable: true,
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
      floatingFilter: this.hasFloatingFilter
    };
```

toggleFilter:

```
toggleFloatingFilter() {
    this.hasFloatingFilter = !this.hasFloatingFilter;
    this.clearSelectedRows();
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
    this.defaultColumnDefs = {...this.defaultColumnDefs, floatingFilter: this.hasFloatingFilter};
    if (!this.hasFloatingFilter) {
      this.gridApi.setFilterModel(null);
      this.loadData();
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    }, 0);
  }
```

GridHTML:

```
<app-data-grid
          [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
          [defaultColDef]="defaultColumnDefs"
          [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
          [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
          [rowData]="rowData"
          [hasMultipleRows]="rowSelection"
          [hasRowAnimation]="hasRowAnimation"
          [multiSortKey]="multiSortKey"
          (rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged()"
          (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
          (rowClicked)="gotoDetailView($event)"
          (sortChanged)="onSortChanged($event)"
          (columnResized)="onColumnResized()"
          (gridReady)="OnGridReady($event)"
        >
        </app-data-grid>
```

AppDataGrid Component:

```
export class DataGridComponent {
  gridApi;
  gridColumnApi;

  constructor() {}
  @Input() columnDefs: DeviceColumns;
  @Input() rowData: any[];
  @Input() overlayNoRowsTemplate: any;
  @Input() defaultColDef: any;
  @Input() hasMultipleRows: boolean;
  @Input() hasRowAnimation: boolean;
  @Input() hasFloatingFilter: boolean;
  @Input() frameworkComponents: any;
  @Input() multiSortKey: string;
  @Output() gridReady = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() selectionChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() rowClicked = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() rowDataChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() sortChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() columnResized = new EventEmitter();

  onGridReady(params): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridReady.emit(params);
    this.gridApi.setGridAutoHeight(true);
  }

  onSelectionChanged(): void {
    this.selectionChanged.emit(this.gridApi);
  }

  onRowClicked(params): void {
    this.rowClicked.emit(params.data);
  }

  onRowDataChanged(): void {
    this.rowDataChanged.emit();
  }

  onSortChanged(params): void {
    this.sortChanged.emit(params.api.getSortModel());
  }

  onColumnResized() {
    this.columnResized.emit(this.gridApi);
  }
}
```

Ag-Grid HTML

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
  (rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged()"
  (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
  (sortChanged)="onSortChanged($event)"
  [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
  [rowSelection]="hasMultipleRows"
  [animateRows]="hasRowAnimation"
  [multiSortKey]="multiSortKey"
  (columnResized)="onColumnResized()"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/w2UDNd4u657tdr0Q?preview

Current behavior
Not showing the floating filter during button click (When the flaotingFilter is false by default and it is changed to true dynmically)

Expected behavior
It should show the floating filter when

ag-Grid version: 23.2.1

Comment: There are a couple of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580909/9449426) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54539454/9449426). If all don't work, consider filing an issue on [github](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues) and hope for the best.

Comment: @NearHuscarl i have looked into those issues and i have implemented some of them in my code.The problem is when we set the floating filter dynamically then at that time floating filter is not shown.You can check the plunker which i have added

Comment: I don't use angular but the code in vue works (the second answer I linked). Though there may be something else wrong with newer versions of agGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do this with columnDefs instead of defaultColDef. [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xakyuwrPA9p2Kunw)

```
showFilter() {  
    /*  
    this.defaultColDef = {...this.defaultColDef, floatingFilter: true};

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
    }, 0);*/
     var columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
    columnDefs.forEach(function (colDef, index) {
    colDef.floatingFilter = true;
  });
  this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
  }
```

Also AG grid merges `defaultColDefs` with `colDefs` while rendering the grid and then uses `colDefs` object in `setupFloatingFilter` method thus setting value in defaultColDefs is of no use.

Calling `gridApi.setColumnDefs` calls `HeaderContainer.prototype.init` thus rendering your filter component whereas calling `refreshHeader` interanlly calls `gridPanel.setHeaderAndFloatingHeights` and `headerRootComp.refreshHeader` but there is no call to `init` function which will render your filter component.

Answer (score 0):

To update defaultColDef in agGrid you can use  `setDefaultColDef` method in gridApi passing there the brand new colDef. And do not forget to refresh all headers.

```
this.gridApi.api.setDefaultColDef({
        ...this.defaultColDef,
        floatingFilter: true
    });
    this.gridApi.api.refreshHeader();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than accepted answer.